# Boundedness, Total Boundedness and Compactness in Normed linear spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have been asked to prove the following:

a) Let $X=(\mathbb{R}^3,\Vert \cdot \Vert_2)$, $I=[0,1]$ and let $Y=I\times I\times I$. Prove that $Y$ is totally bounded.

b) Let $Z=(\mathbb{R}^2,\Vert \cdot \Vert_1)$ and let $U=I^2$. Prove that $U$ is totally bounded.

c) Prove that $I^2\setminus(0,0)$ is not compact in $(\mathbb{R}^n,\Vert \cdot \Vert_2)$.

Proposition. For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, every bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is totally bounded.

I have used the above proposition in questions a) and b), that both $Y$ and $U$ are a bounded subsets  of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and therefore they must be totally bounded. However for question c) I would like some help. I would appreciate alternative proofs for a) and b).

Comment: The sequence $((1/n,1/n))$ is a sequence in $I^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ with limit $(0,0) \ne I^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$. Conclusion ?

Comment: That means $I^2\setminus (0,0)$ is not closed. Therefore not compact!?

Comment: Yes, in $ \mathbb R^n$ we have "compact" $ \iff $ "closed and bounded."

Comment: Can I ask for a) and b) is my reasoning sufficient?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: I would appreciate alternate proofs if you can. It just seems too easy.

Comment: @Nash A proof being easy does not make it wrong. What exactly don't you believe?

Comment: I know. Thank you